# My complex object loses its Data when posting with mvc 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, posting

hi I'm tryin to post a complex class
witcht itzelf holds different comlex classes

```
    public static readonly PropertyInfo<List<RoomsWithServices>> RoomsWithServicesListProperty = RegisterProperty<List<RoomsWithServices>>(c => c.RoomsWithServicesList);
    public List<RoomsWithServices> RoomsWithServicesList
    {
        get { return GetProperty(RoomsWithServicesListProperty); }
        set { SetProperty(RoomsWithServicesListProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly PropertyInfo<List<SelectableBookingService>> BookingServicesProperty = RegisterProperty<List<SelectableBookingService>>(c => c.BookingServices);
    public List<SelectableBookingService> BookingServices
    {
        get { return GetProperty(BookingServicesProperty); }
        set { SetProperty(BookingServicesProperty, value); }
    }
```

But when I post the model is empty the model is build correctly en shows me the correct data.  But when i try to post the data given to me by the post is empty

```
@foreach (RoomsWithServices item in Model.RoomsWithServicesList)
{
    <div>
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Room.VideoConferencingRoomId)
    @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Room.Name)
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => item.Room.Name)
    @foreach (SelectableRoomService service in item.RoomService)
    {
        <div>
        @Html.EditorFor(m => service.IsSelected)| @Html.DisplayFor(m => service.RoomService.ServiceName) | @Html.DisplayFor(m => service.RoomService.Price)
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => service.RoomService.ServiceName) 
        @Html.HiddenFor(m => service.RoomService.Price)
        </div>
    }                                          
    </div>
}
</div>
<div>
<h2>BookingServies</h2>
@foreach (SelectableBookingService item in Model.BookingServices)
{
    <div>
    @Html.EditorFor(m => item.IsSelected)| @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Service.Name) | @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Service.Price)
    </div>
}
</div>

<input type="submit" name="RoomsWithServicesListAndBookingServices" value="Confirm Selected Services"/> 
</fieldset>
```

}

How can i solve this problem

Thx

Comment: can you show the controller ?

Comment: This article will help you to write correct view for List http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx